# Macro Expansion in Tabular Environment

Tags: tables, macros, foreach

I have many tab separated csv files which I would like to convert into  tables automatically in tabular environment of latex. Tables are named: **log_%** where % can be one of the symbols \in {at,be,fr,....}. For example each file looks like below:

```
 
accuracy    timepred    timelearn   timelearn2  timelearn4  rmsetrain
0.987747    0.532   2.44    nan nan 0.987676
0.987747    0.528   2.396   nan nan 0.987676
0.987747    0.544   2.408   nan nan 0.987676
0.987747    0.496   2.388   nan nan 0.987676
0.987747    0.436   2.432   nan nan 0.987676
0.987747    0.428   2.444   nan nan 0.987676
0.987747    0.464   2.452   nan nan 0.987676
0.987747    0.428   2.452   nan nan 0.987676
0.987747    0.464   2.46    nan nan 0.987676
0.987747    0.484   2.448   nan nan 0.987676
```

I tried the below code which unfortunately does not work!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\newcounter{listtotal}\newcounter{listcntr}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\names}{o}{%
  \setcounter{listtotal}{0}\setcounter{listcntr}{-1}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{listtotal}}%
  \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\namesarray}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\namesarray}% \names
    {% \names[]
     \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{listcntr}\ifnum\value{listcntr}=#1\relax##1\fi}%
     \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\namesarray}}%
}
```

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\namesarray}{at,br,cz,dk,fi,ie,nb,no,pt,se,be,ch,de,es,fr,it,nl,pl,ru,uk}%
\foreach \i in {0,...,20}{
\newcommand{\name}{\names[\i]}
\name
\csvautotabular[separator=tab]{logs/log_\names[\i]} \par
}
\end{document}

By executing above code I get an error:

```
! Package csvsimple Error: File 'logs/log_\names [0]' not existent, not readable, or empty!.
```

The same example works by hard coding the symbol as follows:

```
\csvautotabular[separator=tab]{logs/log_at} \par
```

in place of

```
\csvautotabular[separator=tab]{logs/log_\names[\i]} \par
```

I uploaded the working solution by hardcoding on the following link:
goo.gl/nbI5TQ
I believe the problem is that macro \i gets expanded and tabular environment fails to expand \names. But I am not sure. Is it possible to expand the macro \names[\i] as a group and not just \i?
I would appreciate any kind of minimal help to solve my problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean that you uploaded the working solution? If you've solved the problem, what are you asking exactly?

Comment: Working solution is the one I obtained by **hardcoding** the symbol **at** in place of **\names[\i]**. What I wanted was a generalized solution with symbols - at,br,...,etc. expanded in for loop.

Comment: Your code does not give the error you report - it doesn't get that far. Do you need to load `pgffor`?

Comment: well actually, `pgfplotstable`. I will edit.

Comment: This seems excessively complicated given that all you seem to want to do is to loop over the files. I don't see the point of most of it at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code seems overly complex. If you just want to loop over the list of files, I think you just need a loop from `etoolbox`, say, and the relevant command from `csvsimple`.

For example with `logs/log_at`:

```
accuracy        timepred        timelearn       timelearn2      timelearn4      rmsetrain                                                           
0.987747        0.532   2.44    nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.528   2.396   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.544   2.408   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.496   2.388   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.436   2.432   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.428   2.444   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.464   2.452   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.428   2.452   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.464   2.46    nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.484   2.448   nan     nan     0.987676
```

and `logs/log_br`:

```
accuracy        timepred        timelearn       timelearn2      timelearn4      rmsetrain                                                           
0.987747        0.532   2.44    nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.528   2.396   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.544   2.408   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.496   2.388   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.436   2.432   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.428   2.444   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.464   2.452   nan     nan     0.987676                                                                                            
0.987747        0.428   2.452   nan     nan     0.987676
0.987747        0.464   2.46    nan     nan     0.987676
0.987747        0.484   2.448   nan     nan     0.987676
```

The `.tex` code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\providecommand*\do{}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\do[1]{%
  #1
  \csvautotabular[separator=tab]{logs/log_#1}\par
}
\docsvlist{at,br}%,cz,dk,fi,ie,nb,no,pt,se,be,ch,de,es,fr,it,nl,pl,ru,uk}%
\end{document}
```

produces the following output

[image: working output]

Note that this code assumes files are called `logs/log_<xx>.tex` or that the files are `logs/log_<xx>`. If they have a different extension, you need to specify it.

Comment: Well yes files are logs/log_<xx> except the fact that they do not have any extension.

Comment: I get an error `missing $ inserted` if I ignore the created files.

Comment: I ran it without the code to create the files and moved those I made earlier to `logs/`, deleting the extensions. So I have `logs/log_at` and `logs/log_br`. I then recompiled the code and it works fine for me. Apparently, it will check for the file name without extension, as well as with the default extension `.tex`. So it should work fine for your case. Please check with a minimal set up using my code i.e. make a clean directory and create `logs/log_at` and `logs/log_br` with the specified contents. Then put my code (without the file creation code) in a `.tex` file and compile.

Comment: @Sumit If you still get an error in that case, please add `\listfiles` as the first line and post the log file in your question. If not, the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: It works with a clean directory and I could reproduce the output you produced, but is not working with my files for some reason

Comment: @Sumit Without code which I can use to reproduce the error, I can't really say anything helpful. You need to reduce it down to a minimal example so the problem can be reproduced. Then I can try to help (or somebody else). Try commenting out this part of the document to make sure the problem isn't elsewhere. Then try including the first half of the files. If that works, add half of the remainder. If not, try the first quarter. Etc. Maybe the issue is in one of the files. Hard to guess.

Comment: I can reproduce the error by taking a `tab` separated file. Problem with writing file via code is that all `tabs` get replaced by `multiple spaces`. Not sure why is that causing problem though. I will think more about it.

Comment: @Sumit Please see edit. It works fine for me with tabs. Improves the output somewhat, too, of course.

Comment: If I keep the file here - goo.gl/CcdKkE and here - goo.gl/10hcbP in ./logs/, the code above works fine except that I do not get any columns like here - goo.gl/sbxTuz. Any ideas? –

Comment: @Sumit I suggest asking a follow-up question which includes a minimal example with the files and links to this one. The question you have now isn't really related to the original question and you may get somebody who really knows the package giving a good solution. In any case, having a proper example which people can use to reproduce the new problem will help regardless of whether people know the package or not.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that

1. `\csvautotabular[separator=tab]` means that you need to use tabs instead of spaces for separating items within a line of the csv file.
2. the way in which TeX does process filenames is not the same on all platforms.
   E.g., when using MiKTeX 2.9 under Windows 7, TeX always assumes the filename-extension ".tex" if no filename-extension is provided. If the filename in question does not have an extension at all, you need to provide the dot (with no extension) anyway.
   E.g. if you wish to specify the file "log_at" in the current directory's sub-directory "logs", you need to write `./logs/log_at.` . (If you specify 
   `./logs/log_at` (without trailing dot), (MiK)TeX will seek for the file "log_at.tex" in the current directory's sub-directory "logs".